# How to Redirect in Liferay Portal using JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, liferay, liferay-6

what is the way to redirect to another page inside the portlet in liferay using jsf? I have been trying window.location.href through javascript but it tries to redirect the page not the portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on to which page you want to redirect to.

- Redirection to first page of another portlet.

  Suppose you have portlet1 and from portlet1 you want  to redirect to portlet2. If the URL of portlet2 is http:/yourDomain/**web/portal/portlet2** then below code will redirect to first page of portlet2 from portlet1

  `FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();`
  `javax.faces.context.ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();`
  `externalContext.redirect("/web/portal/portlet2");`

Above code will hit portlet2 and depending on your welcome page configuration (in `phaselistener` or in `portlet.xml` your first page will gets displayed.

- Redirecting to some other page (instead of welcome page) of Portlet2 from Portlet1.

Lets say you want to redirect to 3rd page of your Portlet2 from Portlet1. In this case, using the above code you can hit Portlet2. This will invoke `PhaseListenter`. Here you can check which page you want to redirect to and accordingly use below code.

```
if(someConditionIsMet)
{   
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIViewRoot newPage = context.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(context,"/your3rdPage.jsf");
 context.setViewRoot(newPage);
context.renderResponse();
}
```

- Redirecting to some page in the same Portlet

I think you are not looking answer for this case. Still, I assume as I am not fully clear about your question.

Lets say you are invoking a link through `h:commandLink` or `h:commandButton`. And you are invoking a method(which returns `String`). Then  below code can be used.

```
public String someMethod()
{
 //Do your checks here
return "success";
  }
```

This has to be configured in your `faces-config.xml` file.

```
<navigation-rule>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/yourRequiredPage.jsf</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```